# C-Ray test from Phoronix-Test-Suite

Tags: gpu, cpu, benchmarking, pts

I am confused by the C-Ray test included in the Phoronix-Test-Suite. It says on the website, "This thing only measures 'floating point CPU performance' and   nothing more, and it's good that nothing else affects the results."

What I need to know is whether this test uses some kind of GPU too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, C-Ray is purely CPU based at this time.